# kAudioFormatAppleIMA4 undeclared

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I just updated to use XCode 4 and got the following error when running one of the previous projects:

Use of Undeclared Identifier 'kAudioFormatAppleIMA4'

The AVFoundation.framework is linked and  is imported to that file.

Any ideas why this error started to occur?

Thanks,

Sami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you also included the CoreAudio.framework? I believe that kAudioFormatAppleIMA4 is in there.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a problem like this, check the documentation. When you search for kAudioFormatAppleIMA4 in the docs and scroll to the top of the page you fine, it says:

```
Core Audio Data Types Reference

Framework   
CoreAudio/CoreAudio.h
Declared in 
CoreAudioTypes.h
```

This means you must link to CoreAudio framework and import `CoreAudio/CoreAudio.h`.